# Elasticsearch: Can I return only the cardinality of a buckets agg, without returning all the buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, cardinality

Take the following query and result,

```
    POST index/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "perDeviceAggregation": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "deviceID"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "score_avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "device_score" 
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "count":{
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "deviceID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

result:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "aads": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "aa",
              "doc_count": 3,
              "score_avg": {
                "value": 3.8
              }
            },
           {
              "key": "bb",
              "doc_count": 1,
              "score_avg": {
                "value": 3.8
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "count": {
          "value": 2
        }
      }
```

That's great. But in my situation, I don't really care about information about each bucket. I only want to know the # of buckets. Something like the following:

```
"aggregations": {
    "aads": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "bucket_count": 2
    }
  }
```

Is this possible in Elasticsearch?

Edit:

You might wonder why I calculate an average (which limits using terms instead of cardinality) if I don't care about what's in buckets. I do use the average to do a range aggregation. My actual problem is like folowing: The above question was simplified.

```
 POST index/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs" : {
        "mos_over_time" : {
          "range" : {
            "field" : "device_score",
            "ranges" : [
              { "from" : 0.0, "to" : 2.6 },
              { "from" : 2.6, "to" : 4.0 },
              { "from" : 4.0 }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "perDeviceAggregation": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "deviceID"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "score_avg": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "device_score" 
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "count":{
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "deviceID"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't care about the buckets, why are you using the `terms` aggregation at all? Why not just use `cardinality`?

Comment: Well my actual situation is much more complicated than this. I calculate an average on each of these deviceId buckets. I have a range query that wraps this query to seperate the devices based on the average. SO ultimately I want how many unique device ids are in a specific range.

Comment: In short what I want is a way to have a aggregation query, but not return the buckets

Comment: You cannot just throw away buckets, but even in your more complicated example, just using cardinality would work within your range query buckets (which it seems you still want. Just don't use the `perDeviceAggregation` because, as you said, you don't care about those buckets.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, he has updated the query in question. We have more clarity, I used to think we can set `size` to `0` in terms aggregation but it has been removed as mentioned in the link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/term-aggregation-size-0/64278. Plus that would impact its pipelined aggregation too and along with it, many other features too. That being said, @ben, I don't think that is possible. Hope you manage with what you have. I've deleted my answer as it servers no purpose.

Comment: Thanks you both. I'm fine with this implementation, I'm only trying to do this because of the new cannot exceed 10k buckets in newer versions warning I was getting from ElasticSearch